# Traversing an object getting the key and all parents keys

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree, traversal

traverse tree(json), fulfill getKeys(data, str) function using JS. get the key and all parents keys.

```
const data = {
  key1: 'str1',
  key2: {
    key3: 'str3',
    key4: 'str4',
    key5: {
      key6: 'str6',
      key7: 'str7',
      key8: 'str8',
    },
  }
}
```

for example:

getKeys(data, 'str1');
return: 'key1'

getKeys(data, 'str3');
return: 'key2, key3'

getKeys(data, 'str6');
return: 'key2, key5, key6'

I think it can be done be recursion, but how?

this is my solution, but failed

```
let s = [];
function getKeys(data, str, key='') {
  if (key !== '') {
    s.push(key);
  }
  for (item in data) {
    if (typeof data[item] === 'object') {
      getKeys(data[item], str, item);
    } else if (data[item] === str) {
      s.push(item);
      return s;
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to vote to re-open BUT: please edit once more and describe in what way the code you've tried fails. That will help people better understand how to answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it populates the "found" list unconditionally, no matter if the value is actually under the currently processed branch or not. Consider for example:

```
data = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2
    },
    d: {
        e: {
            e1: 3,
            e2: 33,
        },
        f: {
            f1: 4,
            f2: 44,
        },
    }
};
```

when doing `getKeys(data, 44)`, the return will be `[ 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f2' ]`, which is not correct.

What you need to do is to check if the value is actually under the current node and add the current key only if the answer is yes. Example:

```
function getKeys(obj, val) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object')
        return;

    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (v === val)
            return [k];
        let path = getKeys(v, val);
        if (path)
            return [k, ...path];

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Georg! You got the point why I failed. and solve it simply. Learned a lot from you. Thanks!

Comment: @ZILONGPAN: anytime ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only searching for `string` keys we can use recursion & backtracking to check if the sub-object of a key is having the specified value.

If it has it then add the parent key in our final search string.

To do this I have used `Object.entries()` to go over every `[key, value]` pair and used `Array.prototype.reduce()` to accumulate the results:

```js
var data = {
  key1: 'str1',
  key2: {
    key3: 'str3',
    key4: 'str4',
    key5: {
      key6: 'str6',
      key7: 'str7',
      key8: 'str8',
    },
  }
}

function getKeys(data, key, acc){
   return Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, ele, idx) => {
     if(ele.includes(key) && typeof ele[1] === "string"){
        acc.push(ele[0]);
     }
     if(typeof ele[1] === "object" && !Array.isArray(ele[1]) && !(ele[1] instanceof Date)){
        let old = acc.slice();
        getKeys(ele[1], key, acc); 
        if(old.length !== acc.length){
           acc.unshift(ele[0]);
        }
     }  
     return acc;
  }, acc).join(" ");
}


console.log(getKeys(data, 'str1', []));
console.log(getKeys(data, 'str3', []));
console.log(getKeys(data, 'str6', []));
```